Peter Lorre playing a young WW II flyer
So, I have this image seared in my memory of Peter Lorre playing a young WW II flyer, in which a flack explosion goes off, he covers his face with his hands and screams: "My lamps! My lamps are out!" It's a perfect Peterlorresque voice thing to say! And yet, I can't find that movie anywhere! Can you help me neutralize my obsession?

The only film I can find that has Lorre playing a WWII flyer is Passage to Marseille.
From the description:

As French bomber crews prepare an air raid from a base in England, we
  learn the story of Matrac, a French journalist who opposed the Munich
  Pact.

Peter Lorre plays Marius, part of that bomber crew who are shot down and sent to a prison camp.
